# Bash unexpected token when using "&;"

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm launching a script via SSH with this command:

```
ssh myuser@myhost "bash -x -c 'source config.sh; nohup Start_JBoss.sh > /dev/null &; sleep 5'"
```

however I'm hitting an error:

```
Connecting to: myhost with myuser
Password:
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `;'
bash: -c: line 0: `source config.sh; nohup Start_JBoss.sh > /dev/null &; sleep 5'
```

What's I'm doing wrong here? I know that SSH is not the cause as the same command fails into a local shell.

I've read some similar thread where there's some mention on Bash version as culprit for some other kind of unexpected token issue so adding here just for reference in case is needed:

```
bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
```

Answer (score 11):

Guess I did not searched hard enough as I found out solution here https://superuser.com/questions/269429/why-did-after-return-an-unexpected-token-error-in-bash 
 but leaving here as reference.

Basically if you send to background a process you do not need to use ; as the shell is already ready to accept new command.

Comment: These are all command terminators: `;`, `&`, `&&`, `||`, newline,

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! Also note that when given the final commands, `source config.sh; nohup Start_JBoss.sh > /dev/null &; sleep 5`, [shellcheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) will automatically point this out.

Comment: Thank you Glenn, will keep it noted.

@that other guy nice service... will put in my bookmark :) Thx